# Android Async Problems?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have a function which returns a list after doing an operation on 700 images.
The function takes some time and hence the app freezes. How to overcome this problem?
I am returning a list of all the images to be displayed so I am stuck now.
Any suggestions with a code will be helpful.

Comment: Where do you store your images sdcard or drawable folder etc? And what kind of List do you have?

Comment: It's like I take all the images of the gallery process them and then I need to show them.
I get all the images in the gallery and then operate on them and return a list of those images to show the final images.

Comment: Loading all images into the ram locks your memory (checkout android monitor to see it). How about implement paging design to get all images. Lets say get all image paths and load them into the memory as 50 and while fetching images load them with bitmapcompress

Comment: I was thinking the same but I am not able to code it 
A bit of code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code in doInBackground() of Async.

You can also perform your task in async within a service. It will not disturb your app.(If task is too long)

you can get your result in onPostExecute().

Comment: What will the UI show till the background thread is working because I need to show all the images returned by this background thread ?

Comment: You can have any sweet cartoon who will say user that i am making the images. :)

Comment: I am thinking of using a progress bar for it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have **1x main UI** and **700x images** that you want to manage?

You could have a variable of public view in the UI thread called "`finishedImages`", then the same method in each of the 700x return data threads that:

```
increments finishedImages
if finishedImages == 700

 then run 1x public method to do the update of the UI
```

. Only then will it update the UI on your background asychtasks.

Comment: but then the user is waiting till all the thread have completed their operation, isn't it?
I am quite new to android programming so I am not able to go further.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to process those amount of data is to use IntentService. Here is good tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183
You can trigger the intent service `onCreate` Activity or on Button press. You will have to register `BroadcastReceiver` on your Activity and after the task is done UI will be updated  `onReceive` BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I want to update the UI with the processing.
I don't want the UI to be updated at the end, I want it to be updated in parallel.

Comment: Then AsyncTask will be suitably  protected void onProgressUpdate(ClassToStoreImageAddress... progress) {
         updateImageView(progress[0]);
     }